# Customizing Workflow Email Design

Tags: workflow, email, alert

So i have a workflow that sends out an email to a people chosen in a Person/Group field on a list.

Is it possible to customize the look of these emails so they look more professional? For example, something like how Alert Emails look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this feature exists in Sharepoint 2010 if you have the Sharepoint designer. The "Send Email" Action in Workflow Designer supports some of this.

The workflow designer's define email dialog box supports rich text and images.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx#BM7

This article has more if you want to take it further.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible but not easy using html inserted directly into the body property of the workflow.  Read more [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-create-html-email-message-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/)